# Protractor does not synchronize well beforeAll and beforeEach

Tags: angularjs, synchronization, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

### Bug report

- Node Version: `v6.9.1`
- Protractor Version: `4.0.11`
- Angular Version: `1.5.6`
- Browser(s): `chrome`
- Operating System and Version `mac osx`

### Code

```
beforeAll(function(){
  browser2=browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
  return user.login(browser2);
});

beforeEach(function(){
  return browser2.get('/other-page');
});
```

and user.login() is:

```
User.prototype.login=function(browserToUse){
  browser.runLogin()
    .then(function(){ // after login it goes to /home
      return browserToUse.wait(EC.urlContains('/home'), 5000*2,'Waiting ofr URL /home');
    });
}
```

### Issue

It executes instructions in the wrong order; the order is:

1. user.login(b)
2. browser2.get('/other-page')
3. browserToUse.wait(EC.urlContains('/home'), 5000*2,'Waiting for URL /home');

indeed, the 3rd instruction generates a time out exception.

It looks like a problem of **synchronization**.

### Questions

Which is the correct way to debug it?

Comment: The order seems correct. Might it be that protractor does not verify in time the expected condition on /home?

Answer (score 3):

Updating this StackOverflow question. This is an issue with Protractor and should be fixed in the next release. For clarification purposes, the issue here is that ExpectedConditions currently does not work with forked browser instances.

to see the full discussion on this issue: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3761

for the pull request to fix issue: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3766